# Running R-OSGI samples service/client code in eclipse

Tags: osgi

I just download the sourcecode from R-OSGI SVN.I tried to run in eclipse the examples I download ,the service sample seems OK!Then I run the client,it thrown:

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: OSGi remote service is not present. at ch.ethz.iks.r_osgi.sample.client.Activator.start(Activator.java:85) at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702) at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683) at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381) at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299) at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:291) at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandProvider._start(FrameworkCommandProvider.java:333) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandInterpreter.execute(FrameworkCommandInterpreter.java:209) at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.docommand(FrameworkConsole.java:155) at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.runConsole(FrameworkConsole.java:140) at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.run(FrameworkConsole.java:104) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

I think the service could not be found by the client.

Then I tried to ping the port 127.0.0.1:9278,it could not be found and thrown the mssage: Ping request could not find host 127.0.0.1:9278. Please check the name and t ry again.

What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is the server still running when you run the client?

Answer (score 0):

- Is the server containing the service still up and running when you are starting the client?
- Are there any errors in the server ? (check also the OSGi log, not only the console!)
- Do you have a firewall running?
- Is the port 9278 taken when you start the server?

Comment: Thanks for your advice!
I checked the configuration, I should not put remote-1.0.0.RC4 in the classpath, but should placed it in the target platform. Before running the service,I must start the bundle remote-1.0.0.RC4.The client work fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice,they were very helpful!

1. I should not config the remote-1.0.0.RC4 in the classpath.
2. I should placed it in the target platform. (targetPlatform/plugins)
3. Before start the service bundle,I should start the bundle remote-1.0.0.RC4.

   The client work fine now!